# VBA: How to insert Activex Controls in PPT Slide on Office 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm trying to insert a WebBrowser (Microsoft Web Browser Control) in a ppt slide on Office 2013 but I'm getting the message "This Activex Control can´t be inserted!", I searched for this issue on web and find this [resolution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2793374), but don't works to me. I'm using Office 2013 86x on Win 7 64x.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, you might be out of luck. Those controls are deliberately disabled in 2013...

Comment: @DavidZemens in my registry does not have these entries.

Comment: @DavidZemens, Finally I did it. In fact the entries of previous versions of Office was impeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions in this [site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2793374) really work, I was doing the wrong procedure. So just to make life easier (To this question have some use) for someone who need this, here entries modified copy to notepad or another editor, save with reg extension and open.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{25336921-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{2D360200-FFF5-11d1-8d03-00a0c959bc0a}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{2D360201-FFF5-11d1-8D03-00A0C959BC0A}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{3050F3D9-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{3050F5C8-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{3050F67D-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM
>   Compatibility\{AE24FDAE-03C6-11D1-8B76-0080C744F389}] "Compatibility
>   Flags"=dword:00000000

Answer (score 0):

Here are the same registry entries for the MSI version of Office 2013:

```html
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{25336921-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{2D360200-FFF5-11d1-8d03-00a0c959bc0a}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{2D360201-FFF5-11d1-8D03-00A0C959BC0A}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{3050F3D9-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{3050F5C8-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{3050F67D-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{AE24FDAE-03C6-11D1-8B76-0080C744F389}] "Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000
```